"Android SDK License Not Accepted in Dockerfile for Windows Server Core on Docker"
I am trying to set up a Windows Server Core-based Docker image to automate the installation of the Android SDK, Java, and related tools like Appium and Robot Framework. The goal is to create a build environment on Windows Server 2019 (ltsc2019) that installs and sets up Android SDK components automatically.
However, I'm running into issues with the SDK licenses not being accepted during the Docker build process, despite using the echo y | sdkmanager --licenses approach to accept them. The build fails when trying to install Android SDK components like platforms;android-33 or system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64.
Below is my Dockerfile:
# Use the Windows Server Core base image for Windows Server 2019
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Install dependencies using PowerShell
RUN powershell -Command \
    "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_windows-x64_bin.zip' -OutFile 'jdk.zip'; \
    Expand-Archive -Path '.\\jdk.zip' -DestinationPath 'C:\\Program Files\\Java'; \
    Remove-Item -Force 'jdk.zip'; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2021.3.1.17/android-studio-2021.3.1.17-windows.zip' -OutFile 'android-studio.zip'; \
    Expand-Archive -Path 'android-studio.zip' -DestinationPath 'C:\\Program Files'; \
    Remove-Item -Force 'android-studio.zip'; \
    New-Item -Path 'C:\\Android\\cmdline-tools' -ItemType Directory; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-win-7302050_latest.zip' -OutFile 'sdk-tools.zip'; \
    Expand-Archive -Path 'sdk-tools.zip' -DestinationPath 'C:\\Android\\cmdline-tools'; \
    Remove-Item -Force 'sdk-tools.zip';"

# Set environment variables
ENV JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.12"
ENV PATH="${JAVA_HOME}\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs;C:\\Python310\\;C:\\Android\\cmdline-tools\\bin;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;%PATH%"
ENV ANDROID_HOME="C:\\Android"

# License acceptance using echo y method
RUN powershell -Command \
    "$licenses = @('platforms;android-33', 'platform-tools', 'system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64', 'emulator'); \
    foreach ($license in $licenses) { \
        Start-Process -FilePath 'cmd.exe' -ArgumentList '/c', 'echo y | C:\\Android\\cmdline-tools\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\sdkmanager.bat', $license, '--sdk_root=C:\\Android' -NoNewWindow -Wait; \
    }"

# Install Android SDK components
RUN powershell -Command "& 'C:\\Android\\cmdline-tools\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\sdkmanager.bat' --update"
RUN powershell -Command "& 'C:\\Android\\cmdline-tools\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\sdkmanager.bat' 'platform-tools' 'emulator' 'platforms;android-33' 'system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64'"

# Install Python, Node.js, and Appium (omitted for brevity)
# (Additional setup steps for Python, Node.js, and Robot Framework)

# Set the entrypoint for script execution
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe", "C:\\script.ps1"]

What I've Tried:

Using the echo y | sdkmanager --licenses method to accept the licenses.
Created a PowerShell loop to process each license using Start-Process with cmd.exe to ensure the acceptance is piped correctly.
Verified that the Android SDK tools and environment paths are set up properly within the container.

Despite this when the docker image gets build I get the below warning while the image is getting build.
Accept? (y/N): Skipping following packages as the license is not accepted:
Android SDK Platform 33
Android Emulator
Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image
Android SDK Platform-Tools
The following packages can not be installed since their licenses or those of the packages they depend on were not accepted:
  system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64
  platform-tools
  platforms;android-33
  emulator

Question:
How can I properly automate the acceptance of Android SDK licenses in a Docker container based on Windows Server Core? Are there any specific configurations or alternative methods to ensure that licenses are accepted during the build process?
Additional Info:

Base Image: Windows Server Core 2019 (ltsc2019)
Java Version: JDK 17
Android SDK: Command-line tools version 7302050
Python, Node.js, Appium: Installed for mobile test automation using Robot Framework

